# citus:truncate records of a table

Tags: record, truncate, citus

I want to use sql command truncate table to truncate all records in a distributed table of citus,but seems it doesn't work,so I have to login to each datanode to truncate each shard of the table. so,
can i use truncate table to delete all records in a distuributed table? my citus version is 10.0.3.

I have used sql command truncate table try  to truncate all records in a distributed table of citus,but seems it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to TRUNCATE a distributed table by running:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE distributed_table;
```

against the coordinator node.